# Why can't J1772 operate DC?

Tags: ac, battery-charging, dc, automotive

In this question, I am specifically referring to the US Tesla proprietary port, and Type 1 CCS (which uses the J1772 standard found across America.)

For a Tesla proprietary charger, AC and DC take place over the same 5 pins. Tesla proprietary chargers come with an adapter to accept J1772, and convert it to the Tesla proprietary plug.

Why does J1772 require CCS/the 2 additional DC pins for DC fast charging, when it has "the same" 5 pins as a Tesla adapter? Wouldn't it have been cheaper and more effective if the 2 "hot" pins in J1772 could alternate between AC/DC when needed (the same way a Tesla does?)

[J1772 pinout](https://evwest.com/support/avc2_instructions.pdf)

[image]

[Type 1 CCS pinout](https://interchargers.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/ccs-type-1-pin-layout.jpg)

[image]

Comment: The J1772 connector is only good for 80A whereas the two extra pins for CCS can do 400A. The choice between AC and DC is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

J1772 was developed and put in service long before CCS was designed. Therefore it was net designed for the current required for DC fast charge.

Tesla developed their connector with fast charge in mind.

Changing the J1772 standard to allow DC fast charge would require making obsolete many existing EVs which use J1772 for AC charging or require that they use adapters.